# Zabbix: Unable to determine "dbversion" and rerun zcat with Error 1050 (42501)

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I followed the steps provided in the zabbix for installation and upon setup i gotten the error

[Unable to determine "dbversion"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQKwy.png)

during installation i had run

```
# zcat /usr/share/zabbix-sql-scripts/mysql/server.sql.gz | mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -uzabbix -p zabbix
```

and now i tried to run again, it gave me a error

> Error 1050 (42501) at line 1: Table 'role' already exists.

What should i do?

Comment: It looks like `server.sql.gz` created table `role`. Now you try to run it again and got this error as it already exists. Anyway, you can try to remove all tables and revert all changes that script made before re-run it, but I think it is better to re-install all from scratch. In such case you can drop zabbix database and create it again if possible.